# How to overload decrement(--) operator for functions which consist of other structure/classes

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, dereference, decrement, postfix-operator

I found a lot information how to overload decrement(--) operators if your class has an int value.
But I can not understand how to do the same with classes which contain structures which contain int values.
I mean that:

```
class Vector{
   Point _end;
   Point _start;
   ...
 }

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
   ...
 }
```

And that is how my attempt to overload operator-- for Vector looks like:

```
Vector& Vector::operator--() {
    end.x--;
    end.y--;
    return *this;
}
Vector Vector::operator--(int){
    Vector temp = *this;
    *this--;
    return temp;
}
```

Also I got worning when I am using decrement to *this: Expression is not assignable
So, how can I overload it in an appropriate way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `--` has a higher precedence than `*`, so you're effectively doing `*(this--)`.  Use parenthesis or the `temp` object.

Comment: If `*this--;` worked the way you want it to here, it would have recursively called `this->operator--(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
*this--;
```

is equivalent to

```
* ( this-- );
```

because postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary operators.

So there is an attempt to decrease the pointer `this`.

What you need is

```
--*this;
```